# QTableWidget Horizontal Header CSS

Tags: qt, qtablewidget, qheaderview

I'm trying to style a QTableWidget using the latest Qt SDK (4.7.4). From Googling, I've seen that I need to do something like this:

```
QHeaderView::section {
    background: red;
    /* ... */
}
```

Inside of Qt Designer, this produces red headers for the columns and rows. However, inside of the actual program, the vertical section headers show up correctly but the horizontal column headers are unaffected. Why is this?

Comment: Could you give more details about what *working correctly* or not means, along with an example of the *stuff* you have in your stylesheet ?

Comment: Sure thing. If the edits aren't clear enough I can provide screenshots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you need to set the style sheet before you call `QTableWidget::setColumnCount`, but you can't change the order of these calls for the generated code.

As a workaround, you can put the style sheet in your `QTableWidget` parent widget or in the `QApplication`.

Comment: Setting it on the QApplication worked - thanks alot for answering my Qt questions! ;)